# Unable to locate package libgstreamer0.10-dev when install opencv

Tags: opencv

sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer0.10-dev

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer0.10-dev'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer0.10-dev'

E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev'

Comment: I can't find a right way to deal

Comment: Would you elaborate more on how you install OpenCv and which version do you use and the OS you use?

Answer (score 0):

`libgstreamer0.10-dev` is outdated. Try using the newest **version 1.0**:

```
sudo apt -y install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```